# Hide Column with NULL Value on Report (Oracle Spool)

Tags: sql, oracle, spool

I have data like this :

```
Name            Birthday             Telephone              Remarks
-------------   --------------       ---------------        ---------------
Andrew          8-Jun-1989           97827197               (null)
John            19-Sep-1988          87920187               (null)
```

I just wanna show the column that doesn't null on the report. Something like this:

```
Name            Birthday             Telephone              
-------------   --------------       ---------------        
Andrew          8-Jun-1989           97827197              
John            19-Sep-1988          87920187
```

How to do that on Oracle Spool? Already tried with `NVL` and `CASE WHEN IS NULL` on `SELECT` statement after or before spool, but that didn't work. Any other way to hide the column with NULL value? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SET NULL` command to fix this.

```
SQL> set null (null)
SQL> select * from dob;

NAME             BIRTHDAY  TELEPHONE  REMARKS
-------------------- --------- ---------- ----------
john             11-APR-16 984563732  no rem
john             11-APR-16 984563732  (null)

SQL> set null ""
SQL> select * from dob;

NAME             BIRTHDAY  TELEPHONE  REMARKS
-------------------- --------- ---------- ----------
john             11-APR-16 984563732  no rem
john             11-APR-16 984563732
```

Or if you want to exclude column you can just `select columns from tbl`.

Comment: Hi, already tried for `SET NULL (null)` but it seems like I missed something here. There is a warning that the `FROM keyword not found where expected` should I adding something else on the `SELECT `statement?

Comment: oh no, I got it. It can be used for alphabetical only. Thankyou btw ;)

Answer (score 0):

use noprint in column definition.
like, 
COLUMN remarks
col remarks noprint
;